# Split on javascript character with specific leading and trailing characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which looks like this: `"foo, bar,baz"`

I need your help with regexp to split it on commas that are surrounded by anything on both sides, e.g. `['foo, bar', 'baz']`

Comment: Is the two-element result a typo or deliberate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may *match* all the substrings you need with `/(?:\s,\S|\S,\s|[^,])+/g` regex:

```js
var regex = /(?:\s,\S|\S,\s|[^,])+/g;
var str = "foo, bar,baz";
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cHleDn/1)

The regex matches 1+ occurrences of:

- `\s,\S`  - a whitespace, `,`, non-whitespace
- `|` - or
- `\S,\s` -  a non-whitespace, `,`, whitespace
- `|` - or
  -`[^,]` - a char other than `,`